# Embedding instagram post

Tags: html, instagram

Problem in embedding instagram post in website. This is the post https://www.instagram.com/p/B2LaIl6pSex/

Copied the embed code but there appears to be a problem in the code. The line
  might not be working is.

```
<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Adding https in the src url, some posts are visible , some are not and throws an error "the link to this photo or video might be broken  or the post may have been removed"

Answer (score -1):

After deleting instagram cookies, everything is working fine. Didn't figure out yet why this is happening.